# Mark duplicates in MySql with php (without deleting)

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

So, I'm having some problems with a MySQL query (see [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483492/mysql-query-select-distinct-column1-group-by-column2)), and decided to try a different approach.

I have a database table with some duplicate rows, which I actually might need for future reference, so I don't want to remove. What I'm looking for is a way to display the data without those duplicates, but without removing them. I can't use a simple select query (as described in the other question).

So what I need to do is write a code that does the following:
1. Go through my db Table.
2. Spot duplicates in the "ip" column.
3. Mark the first instance of each duplicate with "0" (in a column named "duplicate") and the rest with "1".

This way I can later SELECT only the rows WHERE duplicate=0.

NOTE: If your solution is related to the SELECT query, please read this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483492/mysql-query-select-distinct-column1-group-by-column2) first - there's a reason I'm not just using GROUP BY / DISTINCT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it matter which record is first?  If it does, how do you determine which of the duplicates is first?

Comment: Doesn't matter actually. As long as I keep one, and mark the rest.

Comment: isn't this a correct answer?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483492/mysql-query-select-distinct-column1-group-by-column2/2484691#2484691

Comment: @stereofrog almost. there was another one there that did the trick eventually. Thanks for the effort guys. @OMG Ponies your answer was quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have any ranking/analytical/windowing functionality, but you can use a variable instead:

```
  SELECT t.ip,
         CASE 
           WHEN @ip != t.ip THEN @rank := 0 
           ELSE @rank := @rank + 1 
         END AS duplicate,
         @ip = t.ip
    FROM TABLE t
    JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0, @ip = NULL) r
ORDER BY t.ip
```

The first occurrence of the `ip` value will be have the value of zero in the `duplicate` column; all subsequent records will have value incrementing by one.  If you don't want the incrementing number, use:

```
  SELECT t.ip,
         CASE 
           WHEN @ip != t.ip THEN 0 
           ELSE 1 
         END AS duplicate,
         @ip = t.ip
    FROM TABLE t
    JOIN (SELECT @ip = NULL) r
ORDER BY t.ip
```

You can get a list of unique IP rows from that by using it in a subquery:

```
SELECT x.ip
  FROM (paste either query in here) x
 WHERE x.duplicate = 0
```