# MySQL Query Select Unique Timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have a database that tracks user clicks. If someone clicks on the same thing twice it may produce duplicate entries in the database with the same timestamp.

Is there a way to modify my query to only return results with unique timestamps and not the duplicates.

```
$stmt1 = $dbConn1->prepare("
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM asset_lookup
    ");
```

Comment: What entry is created when someone clicks? `timestamp` and `product_id`?

Comment: @Horen, yes. asset_lookup is created with the timestamp value. That is the table I'm after.

Comment: so when a user clicks twice, it's like this: `timestamp = 1`, `product_id = 1` and second entry with `timestamp = 2`, `product_id = 1`? And you want only one row back? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, if someone clicks twice. It will be the same record created with the same timestamp value. I only want one of the timestamps returned.

Comment: it appears doing `COUNT(DISTINCT asset_lookup.timestamp)` will fix this issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

- The join to `product` is 100% equivalent to an `INNER` join because you use `product.product_type_id = 2` in the `WHERE` clause. Besides that, is there a point to count clicks for products that don't exist in the `product` table and only in the `asset` table (if there are any)?
- The `LEFT` join to `event` is 100% equivalent to an `INNER` join because you use `event.activation_date` in the `WHERE` clause.
- The join to `tracking_product_lookup` seems completely useless.
- The `COUNT(*)` may give wrong results with outer joins. `COUNT(*)` counts rows in the intermediate result set and the outer joins produce rows with Nulls in some columns (for example a product with no clicks at all, would still show a count of 1).
- To answer the actual question, if you want to count distinct timestamps, use `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`, not `COUNT(*)`.

The query would be written as:

```
SELECT product.id, product.name, 
       count(DISTINCT asset_lookup.timestamp)
FROM asset_lookup
  JOIN product ON asset_lookup.product_id = product.id
  JOIN event ON asset_lookup.event_id = event.id
WHERE asset_lookup.event_id = ?
  AND product.product_type_id = 2
  AND asset_lookup.timestamp > event.activation_date
GROUP by asset_lookup.product_id ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the distinct keyword. Read this thread it should help you.

[mysql query: SELECT DISTINCT column1, GROUP BY column2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483492/mysql-query-select-distinct-column1-group-by-column2)